# Octave Gui setting restore to factory install

Tags: octave-gui

I have been playing around with preferences in Octave and I did something to have completely messed up the tab text size and I am unable to restore the setting to factory install.

E.g the tab text size is very small as shown in the image

[tab text size is very small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMhnH.png)

I tried `Window -> Reset Default Layout` but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt settings are in the

`C:\Users\(current username)\.config\octave` folder.

You can delete config files to reset layout settings.